# execute DAG like operations in scala Future

Tags: scala, future, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am working on use case where in I have to execute inter-dependent operations (defined as a Directed Acyclic Graph) using scala Future. Basically every operation (say node of DAG) will be executed in a Future and subsequent dependent nodes will be triggered (they should be in a Future too) once the current node Future completes. This will go on until every node has finished processing or one of them fails. So far I have (minimal code):

```
def run(node: Node, result: Result): Unit = {
  val f: Future[(Node, Result)] = Future {
    // process current Node 
    ...
  }

  f onComplete {
    case Success(x) =>
      val n = x._1 // Current Node
      val r = x._2 // Result of current Node
      if (!n.isLeaf()) {
        n.children.foreach { z =>
          run(z, r)
        }
      } 
    case Failure(e) => throw e
  }
}
```

Is this correct way to tackle this problem (Calling another Future in a callback)? Again I don't have proper way stop other running future once one of the node fails processing.

Can this be solved using Future composition? If so, how can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: Every functional computation is a DAG, and you can simply wrap your computation into `Future`s and `flatMap` the nested `Future`s away. If you want to go the "hardcore" functional road, you might want to have a look at `FreeAp` in `scalaz`.

Comment: @ziggystart I'm not sure how this can achieved using flatMap, do you have idea (a sample piece of code maybe)?

Comment: `flatMap` will not work because the return type of `run` is `Unit` not `Future`.

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your implementation if the signature for `run` has to be the way you've defined it.  Any other implementation will simply be a matter of style...

Comment: Ill write an example tomorrow once I get to my computer;)

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov `Await.result(alekseyFutureImplementation, Duration.Inf)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more functional approach: instead of using `Unit` as a result of evaluation of the `run`/`Future` we can have a generic type. Usually you would want to work with results of the `Future` functionally, rather than with its side effects.

I've added type annotations and descriptive variable names so that it would be easier to understand. I also added a few cases to show how it will fail. You can also chose to recover rather than fail everything when failure occurs. However, for this problem if the child computation relies on parent value it's probably more reasonable to fail.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Try

case class Node[T](value: T, children: List[Node[T]])

object DagFuture extends App {

  def run[A, B](node: Node[A], result: B)(nodeEval: (Node[A], B) => B)(aggregator: List[B] => B): Future[B] = {
    val nodeResult: Future[B] = Future(nodeEval(node, result))
    val allResults: Future[List[B]] = nodeResult.flatMap(r => Future.sequence(nodeResult :: node.children.map(x => run(x, r)(nodeEval)(aggregator))))
    val finalResult: Future[B] = allResults.map(cl => aggregator(cl))
    finalResult
  }

  val debugSum = (l: List[Int]) => {
    println(s"aggregating: $l")
    l.sum
  }

  def debugNodeEval(f: (Node[Int], Int) => Int)(n: Node[Int], r: Int) = {
    val eval = Try { f(n, r) }
    println(s"node: $n, result: $r, eval: $eval")
    eval.get
  }

  val debugNodeEvalDefault = debugNodeEval((n, r) => n.value + r) _

  val singleNodeDag = Node(1, Nil)
  val multiNodeDag = Node(1, List(Node(20, Nil), Node(300, Nil)))

  println("\nSINGLE NODE DAG EXAMPLE:")
  val singleNodeFuture = run(singleNodeDag, 0)(debugNodeEvalDefault)(debugSum)
  val singleNodeResult = Await.result(singleNodeFuture, 5 seconds)
  println(s"Single node result: $singleNodeResult")

  println("\nDAG PATH LENGTH EXAMPLE:")
  val pathLengthFuture = run(multiNodeDag, 0)(debugNodeEvalDefault)(debugSum)
  val pathLengthResult = Await.result(pathLengthFuture, 5 seconds)
  println(s"Path length: $pathLengthResult")

  println("\nFAILED DAG ROOT NODE EXAMPLE:")
  val failedRootNodeFuture = run(multiNodeDag, 0)(debugNodeEval((n, r) => throw new Exception))(debugSum)
  val failedRootNodePromise = Await.ready(failedRootNodeFuture, 5 seconds)
  println(s"Failed root node: ${failedRootNodePromise.value}")

  println("\nFAILED DAG CHILD NODE EXAMPLE:")
  val failedChildNodeFuture = run(multiNodeDag, 0)(debugNodeEval((n, r) => if (n.value == 300) throw new Exception else n.value + r))(debugSum)
  val failedChildNodePromise = Await.ready(failedChildNodeFuture, 5 seconds)
  println(s"Failed child node: ${failedChildNodePromise.value}")
}
```

Prints this:

```
SINGLE NODE DAG EXAMPLE:
node: Node(1,List()), result: 0, eval: Success(1)
aggregating: List(1)
Single node result: 1

DAG PATH LENGTH EXAMPLE:
node: Node(1,List(Node(20,List()), Node(300,List()))), result: 0, eval: Success(1)
node: Node(20,List()), result: 1, eval: Success(21)
node: Node(300,List()), result: 1, eval: Success(301)
aggregating: List(301)
aggregating: List(21)
aggregating: List(1, 21, 301)
Path length: 323

FAILED DAG ROOT NODE EXAMPLE:
node: Node(1,List(Node(20,List()), Node(300,List()))), result: 0, eval: Failure(java.lang.Exception)
Failed root node: Some(Failure(java.lang.Exception))

FAILED DAG CHILD NODE EXAMPLE:
node: Node(1,List(Node(20,List()), Node(300,List()))), result: 0, eval: Success(1)
node: Node(20,List()), result: 1, eval: Success(21)
aggregating: List(21)
node: Node(300,List()), result: 1, eval: Failure(java.lang.Exception)
Failed child node: Some(Failure(java.lang.Exception))
```

TL;DR

```
def run[A, B](node: Node[A], result: B)(nodeEval: (Node[A], B) => B)(aggregator: Traversable[B] => B): Future[B] = {
    val nodeResult = Future(nodeEval(node, result))
    val allResults = nodeResult flatMap { r => Future.sequence(nodeResult :: node.children.map { x => run(x, r)(nodeEval)(aggregator) }) }
    allResults map aggregator
  }
```

Loosely speaking it's just a `Future.flatMap(result => Future.sequence(children ...))`. When the parent `Future` completes its result is passed in `flatMap` to children computation. If parent `Future` fails the whole computation fails as well. `sequence` combines result from list of `Future`s into a single `Future`. A child `Future` is a parent to it's children, and so on recursively. Thus the same failure mode applies.